# How did they create such effect on Bluestack website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Hello i just found this site http://www.bluestacks.com/ and i was wondering how they ended up achieving such incredible effect. I know they used css3 and jquery but havent seen any tutorials on how to make stuff like this. I will like to create something like that any suggestions on how to do it or where to get such tutorials will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the scroll event or how to move elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a huge fad (that is kind of dead now, in my opinion).  It's called parallax scrolling.

Google for plugins, or follow a link like this: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-parallax-plugin/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply you said its kinda dead in your opinion so which one is better i your opinion

Comment: I dunno.  I'm not really a designer,  I just saw a lot of parallax for a couple of years and I think it was a fad that's over now.

I am old school and would prefer a more traditional UI/UX.